# Create array of mapped array keys

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to create an array which shows the layout of an array.

This would be the input:

```
    $array = [
        'company' => [
            'contacts' => [
                'first_names',
                'last_name',
                'emails',
                'phones' => [
                    'test'
                ]
            ],
            'addresses' => [
                'postal_code'
            ],
        ]
    ];
```

And this is what I am trying to get the output to look like:

```
    $array = [
        'company.contacts.phones'
        'company.addresses'
    ];
```

I have been trying to work this out for hours but haven't manages to come up with a solution. It needs to work with any layout/depth of input array.

Comment: Ok, you can lookup recursion online to begin with.

Comment: When posting a question, share your attempt as well and explain what actually happens when you run it. We're glad to help you fix specific issues with your existing code but we're not here to write it all for you (which a proper answer to this would require us to)

Comment: Will keep that in mind next time. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some Laravel helper and collection this could be done easily
Here it is:

```
 $array = [
            'company' => [
                'contacts'  => [
                    'first_names',
                    'last_name',
                    'emails',
                    'phones' => [
                        'test',
                    ],
                ],
                'addresses' => [
                    'postal_code',
                ],
            ],
        ];

        collect(Arr::dot($array))->keys()->map(function ($key)
        {
            return Str::beforeLast($key, '.');
        })->unique()->dd();
```

Output:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "company.contacts"
  3 => "company.contacts.phones"
  4 => "company.addresses"
]
```

Comment: Nice solution but this one would fail if the last key holds another value because beforeLast removes the last segment. Say for example if `phones.test` were ` 'phones'=> ['test' => 'value'] `. That needs to be addressed.

Comment: this is working with the provided test data and this is answering the question as it is